# Cannot Register Database

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

I want to publish a database to ArcGIS Server. When I try and register the database, I get this error:

[image: ArcGIS Server Database Registration error]

Can anyone help me?

I am using ArcGIS Server and Desktop 10.2 with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are you exceeding the maximum number of connections to your database? Which flavor of ArcGis server do you have (workgroup / Enterprise)?

Comment: Enterprise required http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_registering_your_data_with_the_server/015400000505000000/

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the max number of connections allowed to the geodatabase. This can be achieved by altering the max number of connections row in the SDE.server_config table.

There is a SDE command for doing this if you are uncomfortable modifying that value directly in the geodatabase.

sdeconfig -o alter

http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/support_files/whnjs.htm